# pkcs11 print certificate validity date

Tags: openvpn, certificate, pkcs

I'm using an SmartCart to store a certificate and use it to connect to an openvpn.
I'm trying to retrieve the certification validity date through the command line.
I'm able to check for some info but I'm unable to retrieve the Validity date.

```
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/libeToken.so -T
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): SafeNet eToken 5100 [Main Interface] 00 00
  token label        : TNAME
  token manufacturer : SafeNet, Inc.
  token model        : eToken
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x200
  hardware version   : 4.29
  firmware version   : 0.0
  serial num         : XXXX
  pin min/max        : XXXX
```

```
$ openvpn --show-pkcs11-ids "/usr/lib/libeToken.so"

The following objects are available for use.
Each object shown below may be used as parameter to
--pkcs11-id option please remember to use single quote mark.

Certificate
       DN:             C=XX, ST=XXXXX, L=XXXXX, O=XXXXX, OU=XXXXX, CN=CERT_NAME, emailAddress=XXXXXX
       Serial:         XXX
       Serialized id:  SafeNet\x2C\x20Inc\x2E/eToken/TOKEN_SERIAL_NUM/CERT_NAME/SOMEID
```

[This tool](https://github.com/Mastercard/pkcs11-tools/tree/master) seems to be able to do the task, but I'm currently unable to add extra software on the intended system, not to talk it involves build and compile to use.

Last but not least I'm trying to run this on Debian 11 but being able to do so on an old Debian 7 system is appreciated.